# Recursively parse all category links and get all products

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've been playing around with web-scraping (*for this practice exercise using Python 3.6.2*) and I feel like I'm loosing it a bit. Given [this](https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/custom-made-cabinet-doors-and-drawers/1000128) example link, here's what I want to do:

First, as you can see, there are multiple categories on the page. Clicking each of the categories from above will give me other categories, then other ones, an so on, until I reach the products page. So I have to go in depth *x* number of times. I thought recursion will help me achieve this, but somewhere I did something wrong.

#### Code:

Here, I'll explain the way I approached the problem. First, I created a session and a simple generic function which will return a `lxml.html.HtmlElement` object:

```
from lxml import html
from requests import Session


HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
}
TEST_LINK = 'https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/custom-made-cabinet-doors-and-drawers/1000128'

session_ = Session()


def get_page(url):
    page = session_.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
    return html.fromstring(page)
```

Then, I thought I'll need two other functions:

- one to get the category links
- and another one to get the product links

To distinguish between one and another, I figured out that only on category pages, there's a title which contains `CATEGORIES` every time, so I used that:

```
def read_categories(page):
    categs = []
    try:
        if 'CATEGORIES' in page.xpath('//div[@class="boxData"][2]/h2')[0].text.strip():
            for a in page.xpath('//*[@id="carouselSegment2b"]//li//a'):
                categs.append(a.attrib["href"])
            return categs
        else:
            return None
    except Exception:
        return None


def read_products(page):
    return [
        a_tag.attrib["href"]
        for a_tag in page.xpath("//ul[@id='prodResult']/li//div[@class='imgWrapper']/a")
    ]
```

Now, the only thing left, is the recursion part, where I'm sure I did something wrong:

```
def read_all_categories(page):
    cat = read_categories(page)
    if not cat:
        yield read_products(page)
    else:
        yield from read_all_categories(page)


def main():
    main_page = get_page(TEST_LINK)

    for links in read_all_categories(main_page):
        print(links)
```

Here's all the code put together:

```
from lxml import html
from requests import Session


HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
}
TEST_LINK = 'https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/custom-made-cabinet-doors-and-drawers/1000128'

session_ = Session()


def get_page(url):
    page = session_.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
    return html.fromstring(page)


def read_categories(page):
    categs = []
    try:
        if 'CATEGORIES' in page.xpath('//div[@class="boxData"][2]/h2')[0].text.strip():
            for a in page.xpath('//*[@id="carouselSegment2b"]//li//a'):
                categs.append(a.attrib["href"])
            return categs
        else:
            return None
    except Exception:
        return None


def read_products(page):
    return [
        a_tag.attrib["href"]
        for a_tag in page.xpath("//ul[@id='prodResult']/li//div[@class='imgWrapper']/a")
    ]


def read_all_categories(page):
    cat = read_categories(page)
    if not cat:
        yield read_products(page)
    else:
        yield from read_all_categories(page)


def main():
    main_page = get_page(TEST_LINK)

    for links in read_all_categories(main_page):
        print(links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Could someone please point me into the right direction regarding the recursion function?

Comment: I would recommend using `scrapy` for web crawling and specifically for your question I would use `CrawlSpider` where you only need to define the structure of the item page, and regexes for finding and following the categories.

Comment: I know. But before getting into Scrapy, I'd like to first learn the basics :)

Comment: @eLRuLL doing `print(page.xpath('//div[@class="boxData"][2]/h2')[0].text.strip())` does indeed return what I expect. (I edited the first code because I missed the index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would solve this:

```
from lxml import html as html_parser
from requests import Session

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
}

def dig_up_products(url, session=Session()):
    html = session.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
    page = html_parser.fromstring(html)

    # if it appears to be a categories page, recurse
    for link in page.xpath('//h2[contains(., "CATEGORIES")]/'
                           'following-sibling::div[@id="carouselSegment1b"]//li//a'):
        yield from dig_up_products(link.attrib["href"], session)

    # if it appears to be a products page, return the links
    for link in page.xpath('//ul[@id="prodResult"]/li//div[@class="imgWrapper"]/a'):
        yield link.attrib["href"]

def main():
    start = 'https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/custom-made-cabinet-doors-and-drawers/1000128'

    for link in dig_up_products(start):
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There is nothing wrong with iterating over an empty XPath expression result, so you can simply put both cases (categories page/products page) into the same function, as long as the XPath expressions are specific enough to identify each case.

Comment: This looks awesome, thanks for taking your time to look over! But surprisingly, it doesn't print anything...

Comment: I am afraid I can't test it, there are some proxy troubles at my workplace right now so Python isn't able to fetch any pages. You will have to take it as a basis for debugging. :) Most probably the XPaths are not right. If you found what's missing, please edit the answer directly, or post a comment.

Comment: Yup, I found the error, apparently the correct xpath is: `//h2[contains(., "CATEGORIES")]/following-sibling::*[@id="carouselSegment2b"]//li//a`. Thanks again!

Comment: there is also another case in `dig_up_products()`. When I reach the products page (so the second for loop), it may happen to be more than one page of products(so it'll be pagination). I figured out that using this xpath: `//*[@id="ts_resultList"]/div/nav/ul/li[last()]/a/@href` will return a list of the other pages. I'm not sure how can I integrate this in the above function. A bit of help please?

Comment: I think you will figure this out on your own. All the pieces you need are there already. I'm not going to write it down for you, I'm sorry. :) It will be much more educational when you get to the aha!-moment yourself.

Comment: Yes, obviously. I can see that you haven't fully understood how recursion works. Here's a hint. Read the final paragraph of my answer again. You don't have a sub-case of the second case. You have a third case that is strikingly similar to the first case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as well to make your script slightly concise. I used `lxml` library along with `css selector` to do the job. The script will parse all the links under `category` and look for the dead end, when it appears then it parse title from there and do the whole stuff over and over again until all the links are exhausted.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

def products_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    page = fromstring(res.text)

    try:
        for item in page.cssselect(".contentHeading h1"): #check for the match available in target page
            print(item.text)
    except:
        pass

    for link in page.cssselect("h2:contains('CATEGORIES')+[id^='carouselSegment'] .touchcarousel-item a"):
        products_links(link.attrib["href"])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main_page = 'https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/custom-made-cabinet-doors-and-drawers/1000128'
    products_links(main_page)
```

Partial result:

```
BRILLANTÉ DOORS
BRILLANTÉ DRAWER FRONTS
BRILLANTÉ CUT TO SIZE PANELS
BRILLANTÉ EDGEBANDING
LACQUERED ZENIT DOORS
ZENIT CUT-TO-SIZE PANELS
EDGEBANDING
ZENIT CUT-TO-SIZE PANELS
```